# NodeJS https proxy don't work with request module

Tags: https, proxy, request

when I do :

`curl https://httpbin.org/ip --proxy https://74.208.146.112:80`

I get `{"origin": "74.208.146.112"}` so it's work but with request module like that :

```js
request({url: 'https://httpbin.org/ip', proxy: 'https://74.208.146.112:80'}, function (error, response, body) 
{
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) 
  }
  else {
      console.log(error)
  }
})
```

I get this error : `{ [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 140735132950528:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:
] code: 'ECONNRESET' }`

I have try with this params pool: true, strictSSL: false, tunnel: true all of a sudden, with different value or one by one but I get the same error.

I have try with other proxies and with VPS and I get the same error ...

Anyone have idea ?